# Presentation windows phone 7 on monitor

Tags: windows-phone-7, presentation

I wish show presentation of wp7 application on PC monitor, how i can do it using usb-connection and without cameras =)

What's programs i should use? I can't use emulator because all inputs, touches should be from real device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link should give you a bit of help with what you are trying to achieve [Capturing Windows Phone Screen on your Computer](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/capture-your-windows-phone-7-screen-on-your-computer/)

However this is a "Hack" so I would proceed with caution!

Comment: Oh, it's working but only on "unlocked" phone (means jailbreaked). 
Officially no way capture screen from device (from words of @mixen).

Bad, very bad. =(